# SharedInformerFactoryWithOptions - Not able to filter based on labels

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I want to watch Kubernetes pod events for a certain application.

I went with NewSharedInformerFactoryWithOptions. I have added appropriate labels selector, But it is not getting filtered out. As I want to filter it using the label: 'app=nats-box'

Here is the code -

```
req, err := labels.NewRequirement("app", selection.Equals, []string{"nats-box"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error %s, bad requirement", err.Error())
    }
selector := labels.NewSelector()
selector.Add(*req)

filteredFactory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactoryWithOptions(clientset, 0, informers.WithNamespace("default"), informers.WithTweakListOptions(func(options *metav1.ListOptions) {
    options.LabelSelector = selector.String()
}))

podInformer := filteredFactory.Core().V1().Pods().Informer()

podInformer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
    AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
        fmt.Println("pod add")
        name := obj.(*corev1.Pod).Name
        labels := obj.(*corev1.Pod).Labels
        fmt.Printf("pod Name: %s\nLabels - %v\n\n", name, labels)
    })
```

I get the output for all the pods, the namespace is getting filtered but not the labels. Not able to figure out where I am making the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly provide the label string in the `opts.LabelSelector`:

```
labelOptions := informers.WithTweakListOptions(func(opts *metav1.ListOptions) {
    opts.LabelSelector = "app=nats-box"
})
factory := informers.NewSharedInformerFactoryWithOptions(clientset, 0, informers.WithNamespace("default") ,labelOptions)
informer := factory.Core().V1().Pods().Informer()
stopper := make(chan struct{})
defer close(stopper)
informer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
    AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
        fmt.Println("pod add")
        name := obj.(*corev1.Pod).Name
        labels := obj.(*corev1.Pod).Labels
        fmt.Printf("pod Name: %s\nLabels - %v\n\n", name, labels)
    },
})
informer.Run(stopper)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to exclude a certain label so it would neglect watching for the pods that has that label?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using the `k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels` and selection packages, you need to re-assign selector when calling `selector.Add` [because it returns a copy](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/v0.23.5/pkg/labels/selector.go#L368-L375).

So, replace

```
selector := labels.NewSelector()
selector.Add(*req)
fmt.Println(selector.String()) // empty string
```

with

```
selector := labels.NewSelector()
selector = selector.Add(*req)
fmt.Println(selector.String()) // app=nats-box
```